# Google Maps is not loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with some project where I must use Angular. It's my first contact with this framework so I can make some mistakes.

I created function `initMap()` which was called by Google Maps API callback (parameter `&callback=initMap` in `<script src="..">..` when I call for Google API's file).

My function `initMap()` waiting for `bag` variable values - it's global variable which contains cities which I want to use as markers. I know that it's really bad practice, but I spend a lot of time to get data from Angular scope - but I'm noob and I can't do it. Let's move on - when I receive data I'm creating new object via

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions)
```

After that I'm waiting for `idle` event and then I put markers on my map.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    // Put markers
});
```

And here is a magic - SOMETIMES map isn't load. I receive gray box, Google logo in bottom-left corner and nothing more. When I put `console.log(..)` in this listener I receive in console my log message.

When I do hard refresh (for example `Ctrl + F5`) then everything is working fine (always).

My first idea is to remove `defer` from `script` tag (because in FireBug Network I can see very long load analitycs script) - but it doesn't help me.

And really please - don't spam with comments like "*noob,don't use global variables*". If it can't help me - please don't do a mess.

Regards

Comment: Let me know if you are able to fix your problem with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **AngularJS** you can `init` your map trough `ng-init="MapController.initMap()"`.

Anyways, you need to share more code because it's impossible to understand which is the problem from here.

You should kick-start an **AngularJS Google Maps App** like:

**HTML**:

```
<html ng-app="mapApp">
 . . .
  <body ng-controller="MapController" ng-init="MapController.initMap()">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**:

```
angular.module('mapApp', []);

angular
  .module('mapApp')
  .controller('MapController', MapController);

  function MapController(){

  var vm = this;

     vm.initMap = function() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 3,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.483, 16.084)
        });
     }
   }
```

**CSS**:

```
#map{
      height: 400px;
      width:  700px;
 }
```

- [Here You can find a Plunker I made with the code Above](http://plnkr.co/edit/4MegQD1KPGCqWXeV2pfb). It really never freezes or cause issues like yours.
- Now, you can also initialize it with a `directive`. Take a look at [this answer of mine about initializing it with a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254687/google-maps-with-angular/34254940#34254940) with [Its Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QqAjHjIxMw9IfbO7irh9).
- And Finally, [Here you can Find another Plunker I made to add n markers to your map and make them clickable (showing information)](http://plnkr.co/edit/mkGAt3nuhuSkuUYzCcUc).

I hope I've been helpful.